# Redirect from php file to html

Tags: php, redirect

Here my `php` code. I need to redirect to another page when `if($users[$name] === $password)` or when `$users[$name] = $password;` but it does not work.What is wrong?Here ajax too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/login_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name,
        pass: password
      },
      success: function(a) {
        alert(a);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['user'])||!isset($_POST['pass'])){
    die();
}
$file = "users.json";
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name] === $password){
        header("Location:chat.html");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong password";
    }
} 
else {
    $users[$name] = $password;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    header("Location:chat.html");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: do you have a file `user.json` with all the users and plain passwords? that's pretty bad. As the location problem you should use `http(s)://www.blabla/chat.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're fetching the page with ajax the redirection will happen to the ajax request which means you will get back a 301 response.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/login_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name,
        pass: password
      },
      success: function(a) {
        document.location = 'chat.html';
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Invalid password');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
    // Send bad request so redirect doesn't happen
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}
$file = "users.json";
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name] != $password){
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Wrong password";
    }
} 
else {
    $users[$name] = $password;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

This will return 200 on success and 400 on failure which will trigger the `success` and `error` parts of the `$.ajax` request.

Comment: can you tell me please why when i do not write anithing in `$name` and `$password` in json file it still write like  {" ":" " }?Where is mistake?

Comment: Because you're not checking if the string is empty, you're just checking it's set (and not null, which it's not, it's an empty string). I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much)How do this: if the file name and entered match, check the passwords, and if they do not match then write a **new pair**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, update your question and I'll answer it

Comment: sorry, do not pay attention, I just did not read the condition, thank you)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to realize about PHP is all of the PHP stuff is done before sending the page to the user, so calling a redirect on `php/login_script.php` does nothing.

What you need to do is return something to indicate success of the login.

Here's what you should do to understand my explanation:

1. Replace `header("Location:chat.html");` with `echo "success";` in your PHP code.
2. Change your jQuery to the following:

   `success: function(a)
        {
        if (a === "success")
            {
            window.location.replace("chat.html");
            }
        }`